# Android: Update a Table Row SQL

Tags: android

I have this SQLite containing a number of 'Projects'. Each 'Project' with its attributes from the SQLite Database Table are displayed in an activity. What I wanna do is, when a button inside the activity is clicked, it updates the `C_FAVORITE` row of that 'Project'.

How am I able to do so?  Which arguments do I need to put inside the update method below?

```
public void makeFavorite() {
Database.Project.C_FAVORITE.update(.......);
}
```

this is how I display the attributes of the Project on the activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project);

        loader = new ImageLoader(this);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent != null) {
                Uri uri = intent.getData();
                if (uri != null) {
                    final Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, new String[] {
                            BaseColumns._ID, Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE, Database.Project.C_ORGANIZATIONTITLE,
                            Database.Project.C_PROJECTDESCRIPTION,Database.Project.C_BIGIMAGE,Database.Project.C_DONATIONAMOUNT,Database.Project.C_ADDRESS,Database.Project.C_WEBSITE,Database.Project.C_SHORTCODE,Database.Project.C_KEYWORD,Database.Project.C_PRICE,Database.Project.C_CAMPAIGNID,Database.Project.C_PAYPALEMAIL,Database.Project.C_ELVAVAILABLE}, null, null, null);

                    if (cursor == null) {
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.project_image);
                            TextView project_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_project_title);
                               project_title.setText(cursor.getString(1));
```

......

Comment: how the table is displayed? are you using an ORM (ormlite) for your databse? or do you have dbhelper class to run your queries/updates?

Comment: I got DBHelper class, I sync my tables with a JSON file on the server

Comment: first read books, learn how to ask a question ... nobody knows what Database.Project.C_FAVORITE is ... prolly it's a String ... String doesn't have update method ... i have to say it again ... programming it's not for you ... you're tring to build app without basic knowlage

Comment: I assume you must be the nerd king. Get a life dude, help me or just ignore my question

Comment: are you using a ListView to display your table data or else? could you please show your getView() method in your Adapter so that I would know how views are aligned in your listview's row.

Comment: Dhruvisha answer is good ... but still if you don't know basics you will have no use for this answer ... DBHelper if it is class derived from SQLiteOpenHelper has getWritableDatabase method ... now u have instance of SQLiteDatabase(Database) class ... then you should use update method ... and Dhruvisha show you how to use it

Comment: @Sergey I've just updated my answer, pls have a look. Thx

Comment: @hectichavana so you code is still based on http://esilo.pl/selvin/LooserSample.zip ... and there is a content provider and you have no direct acces to dbhelper ... you need to change public int `update(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) {` inside contentprovider to do real update since now its only dummy method ... to do so try to read whole http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html notepad tutorial ... it will tell you how to build and use ContentProvider

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KSgAb9bz but really you should read notepad tutorial ...

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading it right now

Comment: quick question what's this 'builder' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try as follows:

```
public SQLiteDatabase sqd;

//Create connection of database

public void makeFavorite(String fieldname,String c_fav_value) {
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(fieldname,c_fav_value);
int i= sqd.update(table_name, cv, where, where_clause);
}
```

If you have no where clause you can pass null there.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add tags to the button and grab the tags from within the `makeFavourite()`-method. Exactly how it's done depends entirely on your application structure, of which you don't tell us anything about.

Comment: I could, but it'll be a long hell of a post with the all the code classes